# generating coupon code

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

I have five fields

1.CustomerID

2.BusinessID

3.OfferID

4.Day of Purchase

5.Month Of Purchase

```
Private Function MakeCouponCode(ByVal sn As Int16) As String
        Dim a(16) As Char
        Dim chk As Int16
        Dim check, tDate, slNo, couponCode As String

        '..............................setting customerID
        If HFCustID.Value.Length = 1 Then
            HFCustID.Value = "00" & HFCustID.Value
        ElseIf HFCustID.Value.Length = 2 Then
            HFCustID.Value = "0" & HFCustID.Value
        End If

        '..............................setting businessID
        If HFBusiID.Value.Length = 1 Then
            HFBusiID.Value = "0" & HFBusiID.Value
        End If

        '..............................setting offerID
        If HFOfferID.Value.Length = 1 Then
            HFOfferID.Value = "0" & HFOfferID.Value
        End If

        '..............................setting todays date as ddmm
        If Today.Day.ToString.Length = 1 Then
            tDate = "0" & Today.Day.ToString
        Else
            tDate = Today.Day.ToString
        End If
        If Today.Month.ToString.Length = 1 Then
            tDate = tDate & "0" & Today.Month.ToString
        Else
            tDate = tDate & Today.Month.ToString
        End If

        '...............................calculating and setting the check digits
        If sn < 10 Then
            slNo = "0" & Convert.ToString(sn)
        Else
            slNo = Convert.ToString(sn)
        End If

        '...............................calculating and setting the check digits
        chk = Convert.ToInt16(HFCustID.Value) + Convert.ToInt16(HFCustID.Value) + Convert.ToInt16(HFOfferID.Value) + Today.Day + Today.Month + sn
        check = Convert.ToString(chk)
        If check.Length = 1 Then
            check = "00" & check
        ElseIf check.Length = 2 Then
            check = "0" & check
        End If

        '...............................concatenate all for coupon code
        couponCode = HFCustID.Value & HFBusiID.Value & HFOfferID.Value & tDate & slNo & check
        Return couponCode
    End Function
```

I am using the above code to make a CouponCode...but somehow its not very hard to crack...Any idea how can i make a bullet proof coupon code in not more than 16 digits????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're generating a 16-digit coup code, and then to validate it, you're using a sort of checksum?

If anyone figures out your checksum algorithm, they're going to be able to generated unlimited coupons.

I think it's better to pre-generate a few thousand or hundred thousand (however many you need) coupon codes, and perhaps make them one-time use (by deleting them or checking if they're already used).

Of course...this depends on your needs. A lot of sites just have easy-to-remember unlimited use coupon codes just to trick people into thinking they're getting a deal.

Comment: This is a great idea..thanks..but i am not sure if i want to do this.Thanks again.

Comment: @SifyJuhy: random, yes. unique random...not sure. you could always pick a new number if you get one that's already been used (throw them in a HashSet) but i'm not sure that's the most efficient way.

Comment: Hmmmm....okay..do u have any idea about Pseudo Numbers or Pseudo RAndom Numbers??

Comment: @SifyJuhy: All numbers that a computer generates are pseudo-random. They're based on an algorithm and a seed. You supply a "seed" which is usually a number based on the current time, and then it applies some math to that number to generate a "random" number. If you give it the same starting seed, you can generate the same sequence of random numbers over and over again. The only way to make it more random is to base on something that occurs in nature. Read the blurb at the top of this page: http://www.random.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want people to be able to generate or guess valid coupon codes, consider using a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a hash function. On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) you can find a whole list of them for various hash sizes and uses. With 16 digits you are looking at a 64 bit hash function which I would not call bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

1.CustomerID i guess at least 3 digits
2.BusinessID maybe 2 digits
3.OfferID 2 digits?
4.Day of Purchase 2 digits
5.Month Of Purchase 2 digits

so in total 11 digits. only 5 remaining.

I would create a longer code and then split it up into 2 parts
1. part are all information that you listed. If you like you can pseudo encrypt them by doing some weird calculations. only important that you can still easily read them
2. part is an encrypted hash from the first part. (take first part, use a hash function, encrypt the result of that hash with a password that only you know)
If someone enters a coupon, you can read all fields without problem, and the remaining fields are used to verify that it is a valid coupon. calculate hash again and encrypt it, and check if your calculation gives the same result. I would use at least 5 digits for the verification.

Here are the functions I use for hash and encryption. Make sure to add the System.Security.Cryptography. You should add those Salt numbers, and store in your program the password. just make sure it will not be readable in any way by users.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System

Namespace Crypt

  Module Hash

    Function MD5hash(ByVal data() As Byte) As Byte()
      ' This is one implementation of the abstract class MD5.
      Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()

      Dim result As Byte() = md5.ComputeHash(data)

      Return result
    End Function

    ' Hash an input string and return the hash as
    ' a 32 character hexadecimal string.
    Function getMd5Hash(ByVal input As String) As String
      ' Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
      Dim md5Hasher As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()

      ' Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
      Dim data As Byte() = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input))

      ' Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
      ' and create a string.
      Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

      ' Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
      ' and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
      Dim i As Integer
      For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
        sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
      Next i

      ' Return the hexadecimal string.
      Return sBuilder.ToString()
    End Function


    ' Verify a hash against a string.
    Function verifyMd5Hash(ByVal input As String, ByVal hash As String) As Boolean
      ' Hash the input.
      Dim hashOfInput As String = getMd5Hash(input)

      ' Create a StringComparer an compare the hashes.
      Dim comparer As StringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase

      If 0 = comparer.Compare(hashOfInput, hash) Then
        Return True
      Else
        Return False
      End If

    End Function

  End Module

  Module Crypto

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Encrypts data with Hash from passToHash
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="data"></param>
    ''' <param name="passToHash"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function EncryptWithHash(ByVal data As String, ByVal passToHash As String) As String
      Dim _hash As String = getMd5Hash(passToHash)
      Dim _result As String = Encrypt(data, _hash)
      Return _result
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Decrypts data with Hash from passToHash
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="data"></param>
    ''' <param name="passToHash"></param>
    ''' <returns>can throw exception</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function DecryptWithHash(ByVal data As String, ByVal passToHash As String) As String
      Dim _hash As String = getMd5Hash(passToHash)
      Dim _result As String = Encrypt(data, _hash)
      Return _result
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a hash and encrypts it
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="data"></param>
    ''' <param name="password"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function SigCreate(ByVal data As String, ByVal password As String) As String
      Dim _hash As String = getMd5Hash(data)
      Dim _crypt As String = Encrypt(_hash, password)
      Return _crypt
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Verifies, if the encrypted Hash is valid
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="data"></param>
    ''' <param name="password"></param>
    ''' <param name="enc"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function SigCheck(ByVal data As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal enc As String) As Boolean
      Try
        Dim _dec As String = Decrypt(enc, password)
        Return verifyMd5Hash(data, _dec)
      Catch ex As Exception
      End Try
      Return False
    End Function

    Private Salt As Byte() = {51, 39, 204, 201, 190, 167, 217, 190, _
                                     56, 110, 254, 186, 23, 56, 117, 222, _
                                     214, 32, 28, 16, 27, 23, 31, 211, _
                                     101, 92, 143, 234, 45, 63, 75, 82}

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Encrypts Data with the given password
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Data"></param>
    ''' <param name="Password"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function Encrypt(ByVal data As String, ByVal password As String) As String
      Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Salt)
      Dim alg As Rijndael = Rijndael.Create()
      alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
      alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)

      Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
      Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
      cs.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length)
      cs.Close()
      ms.Close()
      Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Decrypts Data with the given password
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Data"></param>
    ''' <param name="Password"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks>can throw exception</remarks>
    Function Decrypt(ByVal data As String, ByVal password As String) As String
      Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Salt)
      Dim alg As Rijndael = Rijndael.Create()
      alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
      alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)

      Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
      Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
      cs.Write(Convert.FromBase64String(data), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(data).Length)
      cs.Close()
      ms.Close()
      Return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

  End Module

End Namespace
```